# Excel VBA: Copy Cells from Solver Iterations and Paste Results in Table with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have very limited VBA coding experience so sorry in advance for any naivete. I've attached my Excel table so you can see what I'm referring to.

For a class project, I was given a series of 15 projects. The projects have a series of profit and revenue inputs but all of these remain constant except for one column. I am supposed to use the solver to find the most valuable combination of these projects while minimizing cost. I understand how to do that. But I am supposed to use VBA coding to run a list of alternate values through the table and solve for the best group of projects for each value. The Life Value in O5 and the Injury Value in O6 are what changes. For each solver iteration, I need to substitute these values for the one in the list (cells N11 to O26) one at a time. Also, for each result as I go through the list, I need to make another table recording the projects selected. So for the picture I gave, I would need to record F1, G, H, and J1.

**My question is:** How do I use VBA to loop solver through a table of variables and record the results of each solver iteration in a new table? I'm thinking that I would use VBA to copy the contents of the cells with the approved projects based on the binary solver result in the "Choice" column, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image]
[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CCmX.png)  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CCmX.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CCmX.png

Comment: Read this first, and modify your quesiton: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own. I don't know if this will help anyone but here's my code.

```
Sub Sheet1()

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayStatusBar = False
End With


Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer


For i = 12 To 26
'Enters Life Value for iteration
Range("O5").Value = Range("N" & i).Value

'Enters Injury Value for iteration
Range("O6").Value = Range("O" & i).Value

    'Solve Scenario with given Life and Injury Values
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

        'Sets up a table which collects all the chosen projects into one column
        'so they can be selected and put into a single cell as the result for the loop iteration
        For k = 5 To 21
            binary = Range("L" & k).Value

            'Enters Project Name if solver choses it
            If binary = 1 Then Range("T" & k) = Range("B" & k).Value
            'Returns cell to blank if project is not chosen
            If binary = 0 Then Range("T" & k) = Range("A" & k).Value

            Next

        'Copy the projects selected into a table of results
          Range("R25").Value = "=CONCAT(T5:T21)"
          Range("R25").Copy
          Range("W" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'Copy the Cost of each project selection iteration into table
          Range("P9").Copy
          Range("X" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

          'Copy the number of projects selected for each scenario
          Range("Y" & i).Value = Range("N9")


'Returns the choice column to all zeros in preparation for new loop
Range("L5:L21").Value = 0

Next

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
End With
End Sub
```